# Pagination links is not working in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Pagination links are not working in my blog post in woocommerce...
when i click 2 the second page http://www.freshcropmushrooms.com.au/blog/page/2 its redirect to the http://www.freshcropmushrooms.com.au/blog/
on the otherhand next link is also not working
I use the following code in pagination.php

```
<?php


if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) exit;     // Exit if accessed directly

global $wp_query;    

if ( $wp_query->max_num_pages <= 1 )    
return;    
?>
<nav class="woocommerce-pagination">    
    <?php    
        echo paginate_links( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_pagination_args', array(
            'base'         => str_replace( 999999999, '%#%', get_pagenum_link(     999999999 ) ),    
            'format'       => '',    
            'current'      => max( 1, get_query_var( 'paged' ) ),    
            'total'        => $wp_query->max_num_pages,    
            'prev_text'    => '&larr;',    
            'next_text'    => '&rarr;',    
            'type'         => 'list',    
            'end_size'     => 3,    
            'mid_size'     => 3    
        ) ) );    
    ?>    
</nav>
```

Please fix it for me

Answer (score 0):

> pagination doesn't work correctly with queries unless they're on a page.

you might need to re-read that part. what `query_post()` does is destroy the standard query.

It would be like

```
<?php
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$args= array(
'category_name' => 'News',
'paged' => $paged  //replace it with your aray key
);

query_posts($args);
```